# Is it possible to pass a Razor construct to a helper method, using Razor's @: operator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, helper

I am trying to pass some Html constructed by using razor's `@:` operator to a helper method, but I can not figure out how to do this. The compiler states that the Razor expression is a lambda expression, but it does not say, what is this lambda expression like... no clues at all!

If I try to do this:

```
        @(MyClass.MyMethod(new
            {
                Html = @:<div></div>
            }
        ))
```

The error is as follows:
`Cannot assign lambda expression to anonymous type property`

If I try this instead, then it states it as being a lambda again:

```
        @(MyClass.MyMethod(
            @:<div></div>
        ))
```

If the MyMethod receives a string: i.e. `public string MyMethod(string razorConstructedString)`
, then the compiler says: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`.

The question is: **what type should I declare MyMethod, so that it can receive the razor constructed parameter?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called an [inline helper](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/04/dissecting-razor-part-9-inline-helpers.html).
It's a `Func<AnyType, HelperResult>`.

You can call this delegate with a parameter, and the parameter will be accessible in the helper, named `item`.

Comment: how come I can't or how can I pass `Func<HelperResult>`? it fails =( and I don't want `@helper(Func<object,HelperResult>body){ <div> @body(null)</div>}`

Comment: @Maslow: Because the Razor compiler generates a lambda that takes a parameter.  See my blog post.  http://blog.slaks.net/2011/04/dissecting-razor-part-9-inline-helpers.html

Comment: I've been reading through most of your pages on this subject, but still not coming up with a clean way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Maslow: You need to pass `null`.  It would not be possible for Razor to allow both parameterized and unparameterized helpers.

Comment: I am pretty sure I figured out what I was doing wrong, thanks for the input. http://imaginarydevelopment.blogspot.com/2013/12/inline-markup-delegates-and-razor.html

Comment: @Maslow: Use `Func<object, ...>`; `dynamic` is slow.